# Error when pushing app to Heroku

Tags: heroku

Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.

I have tried bundle update as well as bundle install --without production

How can I update rubygems on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Give this command to update `gem install rubygems-update`

then

```
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

Comment: Where would I run this? On my local system?  Also, is there a command to check which version of rubygems I have installed currently?

Comment: When I type gem -v it says the version is 2.4.6 which is definitely higher then what the message is telling me to upgrade from and to.  Is there a way to upgrade it on Heroku?